# Openpyxl with Python function len() is not returning the correct length value with

Tags: python, openpyxl

Good afternoon,

I am new to python and openpyxl. I am writing a program and in that program I need to get the length of the string and/or number in a specific cell. Every time I run the code below I am returning the number 2 as the length, whether or not the value of the cell is 2 digits, 3 digits or 12 digits long. I need the exact length of the string and/or number in the cell for the program to work correctly. I have tried the code both ways below without it returning the correct string/number length.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
from openpyexcel import load_workbook
from openpyexcel.utils import FORMULAE
wb = load_workbook('Item Upload Process Dataset Example.xlsx')

what_is_on_sheet_1 = wb.get_sheet_by_name('sample_data_lampsplus_10092019')
what_is_on_sheet_1 = wb.get_sheet_by_name = wb.active

print(what_is_on_sheet_1["A3"].value);
print(print(len(str(("A3")));
print(len("A3"));
```

Comment: Are you _sure_ you're able to run that code? After all, it's using `openpyexcel` as an import, not `openpyxl`, as is the name of the package...

Answer (score 0):

You are close with the first `print` statement. Be sure you're using the `openpyxl` library.

**Code:**

```py
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import load_workbook

filepath = 'test.xlsx'
myWorkbook = load_workbook(filepath)
ws1 = myWorkbook.active
ws1["A1"] = "fsdfsd"
print(len(ws1["A1"].value))
myWorkbook.save(filepath)
```

**Output:**

```
6
```

Comment: Thanks you code was able to help me figure out my issue.